# Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'. windows

Tags: java, android, react-native, java-9

While running react-native project I am  getting this error

> **Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.**.

JAVA_HOME path is

> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 9.0.1**.

and my NVM version

**1.1.6**

. [I'm following these steps](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/react-native-android-tutorial/)

Comment: i have followed exact same steps still no luck

Comment: I am working on windows 10 x64bit